# How to keep one account consistent between the two channels in fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

There are three accounts `A`,`B` and `C` and two channels `CH1` and `CH2` in fabric network. There are a transaction between `A` and `B` in `CH1` and another transaction between `A` and `C` in `CH2`.

My problem is that how to keep the account of `A` consistent between the two different ledgers about `CH1` and `CH2`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the data within a channel is restricted to that channel. It is possible to have some state external to the channel that is managed independently of the channel's ledger.

There is a new feature of Hyperledger Fabric in v1.2 (coming real soon... RC1 is available today) called SideDB that allows you to manage such data, though I am not certain that it would make sense to manage accounts in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

The new SideDB feature, referred to as Private Data, is described here:

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data/private-data.html

and

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data-arch.html